# -lmsvcr90 not found during package installation

Tags: python, c++, gcc, visual-c++, cygwin

I was trying to download a python package that is configured for installation on a Linux or Mac. I have a Windows computer, so I downloaded Cygwin and tried to install the package through that. While I was trying to build the setup.py file, the cpp source files were able to be compiled, but the linker would not work because -lmsvcr90 was not found. I downloaded 2008 Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable package but the issue was not fixed. The 2008 redistributable apparently does not support Windows 10, so is there a way to either download msvcr90.dll or tell ld to link against msvcr100.dll? I do not know much about how the Makefile or setup.py file works, so sorry if this is a simple problem.

The package I am trying to install is here: https://github.com/lucastheis/cmt

I am using Python 2.7 and Cygwin 5.4.0

Here is the error code I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1sdd.png

Comment: I take that back. The problem is not the dlls missing but the .lib missing.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)

You would need to link against the lib and not the dll.